# XML data not being mapped to Params object (REST api in Grails)

Tags: grails

I was first working with this url mapping:

```
"/posts"(controller: "postRest") {
            action = [ GET: "list", POST: "save" ]
            }
```

and this xml data:

```
<post>
        <content>I'm posting this via REST!</content>
        <user id="1" />
</post>
```

and my save action in postRest controller was:

```
def xml = request.XML
def post = new Post()
post.content = xml.content.text()
post.user = User.get(xml.user.@id.text())
post.save()
```

and it works great it saves the post which means it is getting the xml data.

But I changed my url mapping to use **parseRequest** attribute to automatically map request data to params object of Grails. 
new url mapping code:

```
 "/posts"(controller: "postRest",parseRequest:true) {
                action = [ GET: "list", POST: "save" ]
                }
```

and this my save action in postRest controller:

```
def save={
        render params['post']
}
```

The result is I am getting **Null** which means grails is not mapping the xml data into params['post']
help!
Grails version: 2.0.3

Comment: Also mention which version of Grails is used.